# Is emacs worth learning?

Tags: emacs

I currently program mainly in C/C++ and Java. I have done little bits of other languages here and there, but I am not proficient in them. I typically just use eclipse for java, and Microsoft Visual Studio for C/C++. I have read a lot of people swear by emacs, yet I haven't really ever used it. I tried it once, but it seemed way more complicated than the editors I was already using, and I gave up on it. However, I am wondering if maybe I should give it another chance, but I want to know if you think it is worth me putting the time in to learn how to use it? Are the benefits that great? And will it still most be useful in maybe 4 or 5 years? I read it has been around already for over 20 or so years.

Also, I am not really skilled at all in unix or Linux or any of that. Would you recommend I learn it? And if so, why?

Comment: I subscribe to the use whatever works best for you theory. I've tried lots of different editors/IDEs, some have been great for me and I continue to use them, others I've played with and moved on as I didn't like them for one reason or another. I'd encourage you to try anything that piques your interest, if it works for you great, if not, hey no harm.

Comment: Learn it (or at least *try* to learn it). Then decide. It's no different than "Is X worth learning?" where X is the name of some tool/environment.

Comment: Emacs is the God of GNU, while vi is the dark side !

Comment: Per Abrahamsen is [the smart guy to ask about Emacs](http://per-abrahamsen.blogspot.tw/2008/05/emacs-is-text-editor.html). Or, better yet, [read his Emacswiki article](http://emacswiki.org/alex/geocities/kensanata/emacs-defense.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Emacs is highly worth learning. While I don't like slideshare, let me link you to [what Matz had to say about this topic](http://www.slideshare.net/yukihiro_matz/how-emacs-changed-my-life).

Comment: This answer isn't helpful at all. It's link-only.

Comment: @t3chb0t A perfectly apt answer to an off-topic, opinion-based question.

Answer (score 6):

I think that it is definitely worth to spend time to Emacs. That is, if you have the time. The first 2 months you do not feel really in control, though every little bit you learn feels like a victory. Now, after 6 months, I am amazed with the possibilities and wrote so many little tweaks. Before, I never did any programming and now I wrote a small little package for Emacs. Life is great.

EDIT in 2019: I do not recommdend it anymore. There's a steep learning curve, and with the great editors available these days it is not going to be worth your time investment. Especially since the amount of people who will be able to add new functionalities to Emacs will decrease (Emacs-Lisp is a shitty language)

Comment: I think it's not worth it in 2018, though I'm still using it. Just use the best tool for the language and use a generic editor (e.g. Atom) for misc files.

Comment: "use a generic editor (e.g. Atom)" - This statement really did not hold up well over (not much) time, which is exactly the reason to use an editor that has staying power like emacs (or vim).

Comment: @mattmc3 I'm still on Emacs but I'd recommend VS Code nowadays. Starts to be ironic. Talk to you in 3 years....

Comment: To be real though, the quality of other editors is getting higher and higher, and it is tough to add things to Emacs (only fewer and fewer people will be able to do so, as Emacs Lisp really sucks). Just because I spent so much time on Emacs, I better sit it out, but it really doesn't make sense to start learning it as you are learning to code.

Comment: @mattmc3 what do you not like about atom? And PascalVKooten I normally hear people praise elisp, what have you been unhappy with?.

Comment: @Cole The terminology in the language is just so different from what you're used to. I know the language but if I want to add any kind of feature it takes a long time compared to what it would take in Python.

Comment: @Cole - nothing against Atom per se, but one big reason for choosing to invest in learning Emacs today is that 40 years later the editor is still chugging and under active development. The list of editors that people used to love and recommend that are now dead or in decline is long (Textmate, UltraEdit, TextPad, SublimeText... and now Atom). Relearning a hot new tool every 5 years is a track many people choose and that's fine. Really. Today, it's VSCode at the top of the pack. But tomorrow? In a few years Emacs will still be chugging along and others editors probably won't.

Answer (score 3):

Knowing either Vim or Emacs is definitely a *good thing*. Even when I'm doing C# development in VS, I always keep an Emacs window handy for quick text transformations, log viewing, IDL editing, Git merges, etc.

If your programming experience is only with the C family of languages, the exposure to Emacs Lisp will certainly do you some good!

Comment: I concur. Emacs is my primary editor these days, but in the past I needed to use Eclipse and yet I would frequently switch to Emacs when I needed to perform some editing task that Eclipse couldn't manage. If you are working in Windows and mainly working with Java/Eclipse and C#/Visual Studio, I very much doubt you are going to abandon them for Emacs -- the trade-offs would be significant -- however Emacs *is* still worth learning for those times when your normal editor just doesn't suffice.

Comment: I know that this is an ancient thread, but just what are you doing that you aren't capable of doing in an IDE? It's not like you're doing 3D animation, text editing is a very simple process, and I cannot fathom a scenario where eclipse/VS/IntelliJ/literally any other text editor does not get the job done with ease.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what your goal is.  If your goal is to become a better programmer, then no - emacs won't help you.  However if your goal is to be more comfortable working with files and doing development on unix systems particularly on the command line - then yes, emacs is a fine editor to learn.  Likewise for vi or vim.

Emacs will surely be around for a long time to come, just like many other editors on the unix command line.  It won't go stale, so don't worry about that.

I would definitely recommend you learn a command line editor of some variety, since being comfortable on the CLI (command line interface) is a very useful skill for real world developers.  Whenever I interview a candidate for a developer position, CLI comfort is a must-have.

Comment: I do want to become a better programmer, however is being comfortable working with the files and the unix system a really valuable or important skill for a developer? I have just been a windows geek since I got started with computers, even though the rest of my family has entirely converted to the Mac OS.

Comment: Again it depends - if you want to work with unix systems, it's extremely important.  However if you want to work on a windows platform or develop mobile apps, it's less important.  Ultimately as a skill, I would argue it's useful to have if only to increase the breadth of your knowledgebase.  You might not know which area of IT you want to work in, so learning a little bit of everything is a good way to get a taste.  For me, once I discovered unix, that was it.  :)